# Update Manager got stuck (but not frozen) while installing downloaded updates. What should I do?

Tags: flash, update-manager

I have just gotten my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS desktop computer reassembled after a trip back home and connected it to my parent's wireless Internet connection. The connection seems quite shaky (disconnects half the time, likely an ongoing issue with the wireless card I have installed), and it struggled to download updates because of the constant interruptions. Eventually, it managed to download the updated packages and started installing them. I got up and left it to do its work.

When I came back, I saw it was still having trouble staying connected to the wireless (no surprise there), but then I noticed that it seemed like Update Manager had stopped making progress on the installation. I opened the Details pane to see what it was last doing:

[image: Where it stopped]

My guess was that the installation script for `flashplugin-installer` couldn't complete the download until I stabilized the Internet connection. I hooked my Ubuntu laptop up to my desktop via Ethernet and shared its wireless connection using [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing#GUI_Method_via_Network_Manager_.28Ubuntu_9.10_and_up.29), and as I am typing this now from my desktop you can see that the connection issue was successfully worked around.

However, even with a stable connection established, Update Manager seems "stuck" at its current position and won't go any further. It's not totally frozen, but I can't do anything beyond open/close the Details pane as the Cancel button is grayed out.

I know it can cause big problems if updates are stopped during installation, but I'm at a loss as to how this situation should be handled. I'm sure it should finish normally if I can just find a way to restart Update Manager, but the question is how this should be approached. How can I safely get my updates to finish installing?

Comment: I remember having a loooooots of problems with those flash updates. My solution was to install flash manually (grab it from a site, grab the library and add it to my Chrome/Firefox web browsers). Apart from that, I would suggest you, to update EVERYTHING besides Flash. After the updates are done, have fun hacking the Flash [;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ideally you should skip configuring `flashplugin-installer` and reconfigure it when you have a stable connection.

You can kill the download processs to proceed without configuring the package, mostly it is `wget`, or sometimes `curl`, but here it seems that it downloads via `debconf`.

To abort the transaction, you can kill `dpkg`,

```
sudo killall dpkg
```

Then remove the lock,

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Then when you have a stable connection, execute,

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but when I run the first command, I just get `wget: no process found` and it's still stuck. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what flashplugin-installer uses to download flash. May be try,

`sudo killall curl`?

Comment: Instead of `sudo apt-get -f install` I had to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: if there's an error `debconf: DbDriver ”config“: config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable” while installing packages` run `sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/*.dat` and then `sudo apt-get -f install`. Had the issue resolved this way.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I did.

First I found the stuck process (number 19123 in my case):

```
> pstree -p
├─gksu(7266)─┬─precise(9756)
│            ├─precise(9757)─┬dpkg(24158)─update-notifier(19121)─package-data-do(19123)
│            │               └{precise}(9759)
```

Then I helped out with bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/flashplugin-nonfree/+bug/1243090 .
By running "sudo gdb" then "attach 19123" and "bt" to create a backtrace.  The backtrace helps the volunteers determine what's wrong.

Finally I used "sudo kill 19123" and received error message "Could not install 'update-notifier-common'" "subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 143".

The rest of the install then completed without incident.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend updating flash manually from the adobe website.You can un-check flash update option and try updating it again.

You can restart the update by doing the following:

open up terminal and run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` .It will download the necessary packages and continue your update.

`sudo apt-get -f install` should fix if there are any broken packages.

Comment: Just trying to run the first command returns [this output](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1449597/). How would I safely stop the update in progress so I can try again?

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a similar freeze during upgrade. In my case it was dropbox-nautilus that it froze on, not flash, but the solution might be similar in both cases. In a terminal I did a ps -a to find out which processes were running, and found that dropbox-nautilus was in the list. Its process ID was 325, so I did sudo kill 325. That killed the dropbox-nautilus process, and the upgrade resumed. There was a popup error message stating that dropbox-nautilus had not been configured correctly and might be unusable after the upgrade, but I can worry about that later. At least the upgrade is proceeding now.